# pandas dropna on series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas table df:

```
so the df is:

Item    | Category | Price
SKU123  | CatA     | 4.5
SKU124  | CatB     | 4.7
SKU124  | CatB     | 4.7
SKU125  | CatA     | NaN
SKU126  | CatB     | NaN
SKU127  | CatC     | 4.5
```

here is a generator

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sku': ('SKU123', 'SKU124', 'SKU124', 'SKU125', 'SKU126', 'SKU127'), 'Cat':('CatA', 'CatB', 'CatB', 'CatA', 'CatB', 'CatC'), 'Price':(4.5, 4.7, 4.7, '', '', 4.5)})
```

I am trying to drop anything with NaN.

So I entered

```
filtered_df = df.drop_duplicates
filtered_df['Price'].dropna(inplace=True)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The result I want is:

```
Item    | Category | Price
SKU123  | CatA     | 4.5
SKU124  | CatB     | 4.7
SKU127  | CatC     | 4.5
```

Comment: Looks like you set the variable `df` to something else at some point.  Can you provide a complete, self-contained, runnable example?

Comment: I ran df.drop_duplicates first is that a problem?

Comment: Show us how you ran it. Update in question.

Comment: added df generator and the full chain

Comment: @KillerSnail Added the reason for the issue as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic issue with your code is in the line -

```
filtered_df = df.drop_duplicates
```

[`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) is a method, you need to call it.

Also, another issue is that `filtered_df['Price'].dropna(inplace=True)` would not do what you want it to do, since even if the values are dropped from the series, since the index exists in the dataframe, it would again come up with `NaN` value in Series.

You can instead do boolean indexing based on the non null values of `filtered_df['Price']` series. Example -

```
filtered_df = df.drop_duplicates()
filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df['Price'].notnull()]
```

But please note, in the example you gave to create the dataframe, the values are empty strings - `''` - instead of `NaN` . If you control how you create the DataFrame, you should consider using `None` instead of `''`.

But if the empty string comes from somwhere else, you can use [`Series.convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.convert_objects.html) method to convert them to `NaN` while indexing. Example -

```
filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df['Price'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).notnull()]
```

---

Demo -

```
In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame({'sku': ('SKU123', 'SKU124', 'SKU124', 'SKU125', 'SKU126', 'SKU127'), 'Cat':('CatA', 'CatB', 'CatB', 'CatA', 'CatB', 'CatC'), 'Price':(4.5, 4.7, 4.7, '', '', 4.5)})

In [43]: filtered_df = df.drop_duplicates()

In [44]: filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df['Price'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).notnull()]

In [45]: filtered_df
Out[45]:
    Cat Price     sku
0  CatA   4.5  SKU123
1  CatB   4.7  SKU124
5  CatC   4.5  SKU127
```

Comment: Yeah the empty string comes from elsewhere. Thanks :D